# How to pipe aws s3 cp to gzip to be used with "$QUERY" | psql utility

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, psql, aws-cli

I have following command

```
"$QUERY" | psql -h $DB_HOST -p $DB_PORT -U $DB_USERNAME $DB_NAME
```

Where `$QUERY` is a command that loads files from a bucket, unzip it, and put to the database. It looks like following:

```
COPY my_table
FROM PROGRAM 'readarray -t files <<<"$(aws s3 ls ${BUCKET_PATH} | tr [:space:] "\n")"; for (( n = ${#files[@]} - 1; n >= 0; n--));  do if [[ ${files[$n]} =~ .csv.gz$ ]]; then aws s3 cp ${BUCKET_PATH}${files[$n]} >(gzip -d -c); break; fi done'
WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV
```

Here is formatted bash code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
raw_files=`aws s3 ls ${BUCKET_PATH} | tr [:space:] "\n"`
readarray -t files <<<"$raw_files"
for (( n = ${#files[@]} - 1; n >= 0; n--));  do
    if [[ ${files[$n]} =~ .csv.gz$ ]];
        then aws s3 cp ${BUCKET_PATH}${files[$n]} >(gzip -d -c);
        break; # for test purposes to be no load all files, jsut one
    fi
done
```

*aws-CLI version*

```
#: aws --version 
#: aws-cli/1.11.13 Python/3.5.2 Linux/4.13.0-43-generic botocore/1.4.70
```

This script works. But when I try to use it with psql, it fails, and I cannot understand why.

How can I fix it?

Here is a script that loads data from s3 bucket and merges it to fat file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
bucket_path=$1
limit_files=$2
target_file_name=$3
echo "Source bucket $bucket_path"
if [ -z $target_file_name ]; then
    target_file_name="fat.csv.gz"
    echo "Default target file $target_file_name"
fi
echo "Total files $(aws s3 ls $bucket_path | wc -l)"
readarray -t files <<<"$(aws s3 ls $bucket_path | tr [:space:] "\n")"
for (( n = ${#files[@]} - 1, i=1; n >= 0; n--));  do
    if [[ ${files[$n]} =~ .csv.gz$ ]]; then
        aws s3 cp --quiet $bucket_path${files[$n]} >(cat >> "$target_file_name");
        echo "$((i++)), ${files[$n]}, current size: $(du -sh $target_file_name)"
        if [ ! -z $limit_files ] && [ $i -gt $limit_files ]; then
            echo "Final size $(du -sh $target_file_name)"
            exit 0
        fi
    fi
done
exit 0
```

It works correctly.

But when I try pipe this fat.csv.gz to psql db using the following code

```
echo "COPY my_table
FROM PROGRAM 'gzip -d -c fat.csv.gz'
WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV" | psql -h $DB_HOST -p $DB_PORT -U $DB_USERNAME $DB_NAME
```

I am getting the error:

> ERROR: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file

It looks like a specific of working of pg (I guess it's due to security reasons) - [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=275417)

So, the problem now that I don't know how to rework my script to be pipe the fat.csv.gz. I cannot get such privilege and should find a workaround.

Comment: When `Where $QUERY is a command that ..  and put to the database`, you do not have to pipe it `psql`. It is confusing for us to find where the problem is. Can you `"$QUERY" > /tmp/loadfile` and try loading the `/tmp/loadfile` to psql. When only the second part fails, we can ignore everything that has to do with S3 and AWS.

Comment: But the bash script is working: it loads .csv.gz files from the bucket and parses them correctly. I tested it. The problem begins when I put it together with psql's copy command. Also, I cannot devide  this  process  into two steps. I should pipe directly from s3 -> psql.

Answer (score 0):

I finally wrote the following bash script downloads files from s3, merge them to 50MB archives and pipe to pg in a sub process. Hope it will be helpful for somebody:

```
get_current_timestamp() (
  date '+%s.%N'
)

execute_sql() (
    write_log "Importing data from s3 to pg..."
    import_data_from_s3 "$EVENTS_PATH"
    write_log "Importing data from s3 to pg...done"
)

columns() (
    local columns=`echo "SELECT array_to_string(
                            array(SELECT column_name::text
                                  FROM information_schema.columns
                                  WHERE table_name ILIKE '${TMP_TABLE}'
                                    AND column_name NOT ILIKE '${DATE_FIELD}'), ',')" | \
                    psql --tuples-only -h $DB_HOST -p $DB_PORT -U $DB_USERNAME $DB_NAME`
    echo -n "${columns}"
)

get_timestamp_difference() (
  FROM=$1
  TO=$2
  echo $FROM $TO | awk '{
    diff = $2-$1
    if (diff >= 86400) {
      printf "%i days ", diff/86400
    }
    if (diff >= 3600) {
      printf "%i hours ", (diff/3600)%24
    }
    if (diff >= 60) {
      printf "%i mins ", (diff/60)%60
    }
    printf "%f secs", diff%60
  }'
)

pretty_size() (
    if [ ! -z $1 ]; then
        local size=$1;
    else
        local size=`cat <&0`;
    fi
    echo "${size}" | \
    awk '{ \
            split( "B KB MB GB" , v ); \
            s=1; \
            while( $1>=1024 ) { \
                $1/=1024; s++ \
            } \
            printf "%.1f%s", $1, v[s] \
        }' | \
    add_missing_eol >&1
)

import_data_from_s3() (
    local bucket_path=$1
    local limit_files=$2
    local target_file_name=$3

    write_log "Source bucket $bucket_path"
    if [ -z ${target_file_name} ]; then
        target_file_name="fat.csv.gz"
        write_log "Default target file $target_file_name"
    fi

    if [ ! -z ${limit_files} ]; then
        write_log "Import ${limit_files} files"
    else
        write_log "Import all files"
    fi

    write_log "Total files $(aws s3 ls $bucket_path | wc -l)"
    readarray -t files <<<"$(aws s3 ls $bucket_path | tr [:space:] "\n")"

    write_log "Remove old data files..."
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*${target_file_name}" -execdir rm -f {} +;
    write_log "Remove old data files...done"

    TMP_TABLE_COLUMNS=$(columns)
    write_log "Importing columns: ${DW_EVENTS_TMP_TABLE_COLUMNS}"

    declare -A pids
    local total_data_amount=0
    local file_size_bytes=0
    local file_size_bytes=0
    local size_limit=$((50*1024*1024))

    for (( n = ${#files[@]} - 1, file_counter=1, fat_file_counter=1; n >= 0; n--));  do
        if [[ ! ${files[$n]} =~ .csv.gz$ ]]; then continue; fi

        file="${fat_file_counter}-${target_file_name}"
        aws s3 cp --quiet ${bucket_path}${files[$n]} >(cat >> "${file}");

        file_size_bytes=$(stat -c%s "$file")
        if [ $file_size_bytes -gt $size_limit ]; then
            import_zip "${file}" "$(pretty_size ${file_size_bytes})" & pids["${file}"]=$!;
            total_data_amount=$((total_data_amount+file_size_bytes))
            write_log "Files read: ${file_counter}, total size(zipped): $(pretty_size ${total_data_amount})"
            ((fat_file_counter++))
        fi

        # write_log "${file_counter}, ${files[$n]}, current size: $(du -sh $file)"
        if [ ! -z ${limit_files} ] && [ ${file_counter} -gt ${limit_files} ]; then
            write_log "Final size $(du -sh ${file})"
            if [ ! ${pids["${file}"]+0} ]; then
                import_zip "${file}" "$(pretty_size ${file_size_bytes})" & pids["${file}"]=$!;
            fi
            break;
        fi
        ((file_counter++))
    done

    # import rest file that can less than limit size
    if [ ! ${pids["${file}"]+0} ]; then
        import_zip "${file}" "$(pretty_size ${file_size_bytes})" & pids["${file}"]=$!;
    fi

    write_log "Waiting for all pids: ${pids[*]}"
    for pid in ${pids[*]}; do
        wait $pid
    done
    write_log "All sub process have finished. Total size(zipped): $(pretty_size ${total_data_amount})"
)

import_zip() (
    local file=$1
    local size=$2
    local start_time=`get_current_timestamp`
    write_log "pid: $!, size: ${size}, importing ${file}...";
    gzip -d -c ${file} | \
       psql --quiet -h ${DB_HOST} -p ${DB_PORT} -U ${DB_USERNAME} ${DB_NAME} \
           -c "COPY ${TMP_TABLE}(${TMP_TABLE_COLUMNS})
               FROM STDIN
               WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV";
    rm $file;
    local end_time=`get_current_timestamp`
    write_log "pid: $!, time: `get_timestamp_difference ${start_time} ${end_time}`, size: ${size}, importing ${file}...done";
)
```